# X11 forwarding from Debian on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am testing out Google Compute Engine (with an instance running Debian), and I have trouble using X11 forwarding through ssh. 
To connect to my instance I use

> > gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-X" instance-name

While connecting I get the following response to the screen

> > X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

and X11 forwarding does not work.
Is this a problem of proper configuration of shh or perhaps something related to GCE?

I hope someone can help me get X11 forwarding up and running

Comment: You can also use vncserve. 

Make sure you have something like GNOME Desktop installed on the instance.

Create a firewall rule to open port 5901, start vncserve on the host/instance, it asks you to set a password, then use a vnc client on your local machine (Screen Share on Mac OS X). 

I thought I wanted to do X11 forwarding until I learned how to do this.

End result: UI running on the instance that I control locally.

Comment: I meant: vncserver, not vncserve (Missing the "r" in my original comment)

Answer (score 10):

I believe that you’re affected by a [Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=422327), that prevents you from being able to use X11 forwarding.

Adding `AddressFamily inet` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting the SSH server should work.

If it still doesn't work, you could you try to add `X11UseLocalhost no` in the same file and restart the SSH server again.

Comment: could you specify which machine - local or gce vm - these should be performed on.

Comment: Those modifications should be done in the SSH server which in this case is the GCE instance.

Comment: `X11UseLocalhost no` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do two things.

Install xauth:

> sudo apt-get install xauth

and modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config by adding the following on a new line: 
`X11UseLocalhost no`

Bounce the ssh daemon

> sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Reconnect with the -X flag and you should be good to go.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as the OP but on RHEL. In addition to these instructions by ScottZ, I also set ```X11Forwarding yes". After that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use X forwarding it should be enabled on both sides. On the server side you need to specify  ForwardX11 yes in ~/.ssh/config. See [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more requirements to have X11 forwarding working.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The thing is, X11Forwarding yes is allready set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. And I installed xauth on the server. Still, X11 is not forwarded. If create an instance base don CentOs, and install xauth, X11 forward through ssh works fine. So, I guess it mist be a Debian thing...

Answer (score 0):

on a macos I had to download xquartz (open source) software.
I opened a xquartz terminal and ssh'd using the glcoud suite command.

this is what I did to fix this:

- downloaded gcloud suite to be able to ssh using gcloud
- downloaded xquartz open source software. restart computer after downloading.
- updated /etc/ssh/etc_config on the target server. I have the following set, but not sure which one works. restart ssh daemon/server after updating.

> ForwardAgent yes
>
> ForwardX11 yes
>
> X11UseLocalhost no
>
> #ForwardX11Trusted yes this is commented

- opened xquartz terminal and typed in the gcloud ssh command with the -X flag
  e.g. gcloud beta compute ssh --ssh-flag="-X" --zone "[zone]" "[instance]" --project "[project]"
- this made me able to connect to my gcp instance in a xquartz terminal.
- after I connected, I tried the command that I was trying to do and it worked.